# show hide tab in uitabview programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to programmatically hide certain tab/s in UITabView application?

How to modify `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`  to hide certain tab , first for example

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after app launch.

    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I tried to add

```
for (UIViewController *v in tabBarController.viewControllers  )
{
    UIViewController *vc = v;

    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[FirstViewController class]])
    {
         FirstViewController *myViewController = vc;
         vc.view.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

but it removes the content of this view and the tab named first still appear. How to remove it too?

Answer (score 0):

use `hidden` property of UIView . since every view is inherited from `UIView`,

Comment: could u give me example , I have tab based application in appdelegate how to use hidden

Comment: To hide : myTabView.hidden = YES; and To Show :myTabView.hidden = NO;

Comment: I am not creatig the tabview programatically , I chose from the application tab based application

Comment: @Ali : Try with vc.view.hidden = YES ;

Comment: it removed the view content but the tab still exists how to hide it too

Comment: Can you access your tab object ?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you shouldn't do such a thing. The point of a tab bar is to present desperate parts of your app, not context sensitive parts. Better to use a UIToolBar for that sort of thing. Trying to hide individual tabs depending on context may get your app rejected by Apple.

That said, if you must do it then you need to use `UITabBarController`'s `setViewControllers:animated:` method. You don't have to do anything to your `FirstViewController` itself.

Something like:

```
NSMutableArray* controllers = [myTabBarController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
[controllers removeObjectsInRange: NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
[myTabBarController setViewControllers: controllers animated: YES];
```

Comment: `NSRangeMake` should be `NSMakeRange`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with "Daniel T." Tabs must stay in place.

Anyway I had to modify tabs based on web services, hiding "profile" tab if not logged.

As a starting point:

1) customise TabBarController creating a custom class

2) implement your logic. (in sample code I even change icons... based on web settings..)

```
/  Created by ing.conti on 6/5/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 ing.conti. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // by hand:
    setupTabBar()
}

final private func setImage(named: String, to: UITabBarItem){
    if let image = UIImage(named: named){
    to.selectedImage = image
    to.image = image
    }
}

final func setupTabBar(){
    guard var tbis : [UITabBarItem] = self.tabBar.items else{
        return
    }

    // set images, anyway.. so it's ready for future
    tbis[0].title = localized("TITLE1")
    self.setImage(named: "img1", to:tbis[0])

    tbis[1].title = localized("TITLE2")
    self.setImage(named: "title2", to:tbis[1])

    tbis[2].title = localized("PROFILE")
    self.setImage(named: "profile", to:tbis[2])

    // for now simply remove controller...

    if !LoginManager.shared.logginAllowsProfile(){
        self.viewControllers?.removeLast()
    }

    // as a convenience, select always 2nd:
//  self.selectedViewController = self.viewControllers?[1]

}
```

}